# Creating DropDown in kivy with only kv file

Tags: android, python, kivy

I wanted to get a simple combo box like widget using the DropDown class. I can do it using python code, but is it possible using just kv language?

I tried the following. Here's my python code:

```
class CustomDropDown(DropDown):
   pass

class MainForm(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.dropdown = CustomDropDown()
        self.mainForm = MainForm()
        return self.mainForm
    def do_something(self):
        self.dropdown.open(self.mainForm)

MainApp().run()
```

And here's the kv file :

```
<MainForm>:
    Button:
        text: 'Press'
        size_hint: [None,None]
        height: '40dp'
        on_release: app.do_something()
<CustomDropDown>:
    Button:
        text: 'First Item'
    Label:
        text: 'Disabled item'
    Button:
        text: 'Second Item'
```

But this is not working. Can you please suggest something? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible using kivy language.

You can read about [DropDownList](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.dropdown.html) or [Spinner](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.spinner.html) through these links. And also if you want to know more on their working, you might want to check this [link for kivy-showcase](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/examples/demo/showcase)

I think the code is self explanatory.(on_select method)

This is the main.py file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class CustomDropDown(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CustomDropDown()
if __name__=='__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

This is the main.kv file

```
<CustomDropDown>:

    Button:
        id: btn
        text: 'Press'
        on_release: dropdown.open(self)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: '48dp'

    DropDown:

        id: dropdown
        on_parent: self.dismiss()
        on_select: btn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])

        Button:
            text: 'First Item'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'
            on_release: dropdown.select('First Item')

        Label:
            text: 'Second Item'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'

        Button:
            text: 'Third Item'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: '48dp'
            on_release: dropdown.select('Third Item')
```

Comment: This solution won't work with newer version of kivy cfr https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/5139

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this in your **kv** file:

```
Button:
    text: "Press"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 250, 50
    pos_hint: {"center": (0.5, 0.5)}
    on_release: Factory.CustomDropDown().open(self)

<CustomDropDown@DropDown>:
    Button:
        text: 'First Item'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44
        on_release: root.select('item1')
    Label:
        text: 'Disabled item'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44
    Button:
        text: 'Second Item'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44
        on_release: root.select('item2')
```

And completely remove `CustomDropDown` class from your **py** file.