# how to dismiss the dropdown menu in kivy without selecting anything

Tags: python, kivy, dropdown, dismiss

I’ve slightly modified the code found here ([Creating DropDown in kivy with only kv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847903/creating-dropdown-in-kivy-with-only-kv-file/30856056#30856056)).

This is the python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class CustomDropDown(BoxLayout):
    pass

class ttddkvApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CustomDropDown()

if __name__=='__main__':
    ttddkvApp().run()
```

and this is the kv code:

```
<CustomDropDown>:

    Button:
        id: mainbtn
        text: 'Difficulty Level'
        on_release: dropdown.open(self)
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50

    DropDown:
        id: dropdown
        on_parent: self.dismiss()
        on_select: mainbtn.text = '{}'.format(args[1])
        Button:
            text: 'easy'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)

        Button:
            text: 'difficult'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)
```

The code works fine as the original code does: when I press the main button the dropdown menu opens and it disappears when I select an item in the menu or click somewhere outside the menu. This is ok.

My problem is:
The dropdown menu does not disappear (dismiss) when I press a second time the main button. When I do this the menu opens again…

Is there any way to let the dropdown menu disappear whit a second click on the main button?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own state boolean variable to see if the dropdown is open or closed. That way you can make the dropdown act as wanted, with a condition in kvlang.
Example of your code rewritten:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty


Builder.load_string('''

<CustomDropDown>:

    Button:
        id: mainbtn
        text: 'Difficulty Level'
        on_release: 
            if not root.state: dropdown.open(self); root.state = True
            else: dropdown.dismiss(); root.state = False
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 50

    DropDown:
        id: dropdown
        on_parent: 
            self.dismiss()
        on_select: mainbtn.text = '{}'.format(args[1]); root.state = False
        Button:
            text: 'easy'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)

        Button:
            text: 'difficult'
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 50
            on_release: dropdown.select(self.text)

''')

class CustomDropDown(BoxLayout):
    state = BooleanProperty(False)

class ttddkvApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CustomDropDown()

if __name__=='__main__':
    ttddkvApp().run()
```